# Will popular Stack Exchange sites get their own domain?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I know Jeff has said a few times that WebApps was a site that would be very beneficial to the trilogy and the oft recurring question of whether migration will be possible led me to wonder.

Will popular SE sites get their own domain, or will they forever be a sub-domain of Stack Exchange?

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248453/why-do-some-stack-exchange-sites-have-their-own-domain-names

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The existing answer to this question was correct when it was written, but the situation has changed. In short, the answer is now "graduated sites don't automatically get top-level URLs, and whether/when they get them at all will be a case-by-case judgment call."

See [Public Service Announcement: ongoing, offsite discussion about Area 51 graduates' branding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area-51-graduates) and the posts it links to for much, **much** more info.

Answer (score 10):

In the beta email, it said they'd all get their own Top-Level domain after the beta period:

> **Q**: How long is the beta?
>   **A**: The beta will last at least 60 days. At the end of 60 to 90 days, if the site has enough ongoing traffic and enough questions are getting answers, it will graduate to a full-fledged, permanent Stack Exchange. At that time the community will decide on a permanent, **top-level URL**, a web design and a logo.