# What's the eligibility criteria for a SE site to get dedicated domain name?

Tags: discussion, domain-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will popular Stack Exchange sites get their own domain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55592/will-popular-stack-exchange-sites-get-their-own-domain)
>   [Public Service Announcement: ongoing, offsite discussion about Area 51 graduates' branding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area-51-graduates)
>   [A Plea For Actual Domain Identities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/a-plea-for-actual-domain-identities)

AFAIK, out of all Stack Exchange sites, only three sites have got dedicated domain name: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [Super User](http://superuser.com) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). All others are hosted on a subdomain of stackexchange.com.
I want to know when a subdomain-hosted SE site would get a dedicated domain name. Simply, what's the eligibility criteria for it?

Comment: There are redirects for some of the other sites. For example, http://www.seasonedadvice.com/ points to http://cooking.stackexchange.com/. I suppose the "official" criteria for having a domain name that is not redirected to `*.stackexchange.com` is that you have to be part of the original trilogy.

Comment: ["For the time being, all sites will stick with their topic.stackexchange.com names."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

Comment: The reason Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User have their own domains is historical. They were created by Jeff and Joel and started the whole Stack Exchange network. SE 2.0 sites don't usually (barring a couple of exceptions) have their own domain name.

Comment: Related: [A Plea For Actual Domain Identities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/103686), [Will popular Stack Exchange sites get their own domain?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55592)

Comment: @CodyGray, that's not nearly the same thing. I'm sure you know that.

Comment: Related: [Public Service Announcement: ongoing, offsite discussion about Area 51 graduates' branding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area-51-graduates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Critical mass on levels compared to the Trilogy and the ability to describe your site in one sentence used to be the mantra passed around.

Previous sites have names based on a previous decision by SE Inc. which has since been reverted.

Up to now only exceptional cases such as sexuality.stackexchange.com have been offered domains. Gaming rivals the trilogy but I have not seen any change in domain. So I think it would be best not to believe you will get a domain. It's just not going to happen unless you are the exception.

See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Comment: Sexuality.SE had its own domain? Why?

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello see http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3938/will-sexuality-be-on-the-se-domain-and-will-this-affect-the-way-web-filtering-so

Comment: I see. So the way to get your own domain is to link your site's subject to something naughty. Get creative, folks! :)