# How does this SE site (beta) get custom domain & brand?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, domain-names

Until now, I thought [new SE sites can't get a custom domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124327/whats-the-eligibility-criteria-for-a-se-site-to-get-dedicated-domain-name). But, look at an Area 51 proposal: [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business). It's in beta. Now, click  the visit button to visit the [beta site](http://answers.onstartups.com/). It has got a custom domain host, custom brand & description. How?

Comment: Probably related to: *It's a part of OnStartups.com, a blog on entrepeneurship by Dharmesh Shah.*

Comment: @sixlettervariables its description on beta site.. it explains nothing..

Comment: I'll now point to the following header text on Area51: *This site was seeded with content from answers.onstartups.com, a Stack Exchange 1.0 site.*

Comment: @sixlettervariables as was http://judaism.stackexchange.com/ but its domain name is not used (mi.yodeya.com) because of stack exchange rules. (http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/951/719)

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Startup Business has been in beta for almost a year longer than Judaism. When was that "rule" issued?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I am not sure. But I remember it being discussed at some point on J.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right from your A51 proposal link in big bad bold letters:

> This site was seeded with content from answers.onstartups.com, a Stack Exchange 1.0 site.

What's [Stack Exchange 1.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)?

> Our first idea was Stack Exchange… call it Stack Exchange 1.0. We thought we’d make our software available on a SaaS basis, a.k.a. “white label Stack Overflow,” so that anyone could start a site on a new topic in exchange for money.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/951/719 <-- What about this?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I don't see where it's mentioned judaism started off as a SE 1.0 site? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning

Comment: see here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from

Comment: @Sathya According to link you've provided in answer, `If your site remains very active, we’d love to work with you to **migrate** it to the new, community-owned Stack Exchange platform.` And, new community-owned SE platform doesn't get domain. So, how does this one gets domain?

Comment: @SachinShekhar onstartups is a fairly well known brand + the SE site was there for a while. Guess they didn't want to break it. Also SE1.0 has been dead for about 2 years, they gave SE1.0 owners a year to migrate, I believe

Comment: @Sathya That still doesnt answer why j.SE can't use their original logo etc -- http://www.facebook.com/pages/miyodeya/223001802878

Comment: @amana: You already know about http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com, why not ask those questions there?

Comment: @CodyGray I have -- http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/951/719 -- But it seems kind  of useless there because it could apply to other sites as well...

Comment: All this is before my time, but for what it's worth, decisions like this are often made on a case-by-case basis.