# Add answer acceptance timestamp to the post timeline

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, timestamps, timeline

As far as I see the timestamp for answer acceptance is only visible on green tick tooltip on the post page, [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126264/339911):

> [image: acceptation time]

[Answer's timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/126264/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) doesn't contain any information about acceptance as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359786/339911).

But even on [question's timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/126261/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) there is no information about time of acceptance, only a checkmark next to the currently accepted answer that has no timestamp:

> [image: accepted tooltip in timeline]

I'm suggesting to add the information about acceptance time to the post (at least on question) timeline, e.g. by using the same text on green tick tooltip as for post page.

Comment: Then by the same logic it should also be added to the answer's own timeline.

Comment: @Luuklag what do you mean by "same logic"? The best solution is to add acceptance info to the answer timeline too, but my FR is a little step forward - just improve the tooltip content. so I'm hoping for bigger percentage of [status-completed] :)