# When does an SE website get its own domain?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will popular Stack Exchange sites get their own domain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55592/will-popular-stack-exchange-sites-get-their-own-domain)

I have noticed that some of Stack Exchange's newer websites (i.e. any that were not part of the original trilogy, such as Ask Ubuntu and Stack Apps) have their own top-level URLs (e.g. `askubuntu.com`) instead of `stackexchange.com` URLs (e.g. `skeptics.stackexchange.com`).

When does a site qualify for its own TLD? Is it automatic after a certain amount of time, or were Ask Ubuntu and Stack Apps exceptions?

Comment: See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/a-new-name-for-gaming-stack-exchange for more information about the only SE 2.0 that's going to get a name (not counting the few - Cooking, Ubuntu, Apple - that *already* have a name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, you have to ask for it.

[The "elevator pitch" section talks a bit about this, but discourages it.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

[Lot more about domain names here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

[Why they are discouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)